# Label and Entry Widget placements, Python Tkinter

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, label

The code presented below creates three labels and textboxes for user entry. I have an issue with the placement of those widgets (which isn't one below the other as it should be). 
How can U place it one below the other? Also, how can user upload his/her image against the IMAGE tag?

Code-->

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
#frame = Frame(root)
#frame.pack()

Name = Label(root, text="Enter Name", fg="Blue", font=("Helvetica", 16))
N1=Entry(root,bd=5)

EmailID = Label(root, text="Enter Email ID", fg="Blue", font=("Helvetica", 16))
E1=Entry(root,bd=5)

City = Label(root, text="Enter City", fg="Blue", font=("Helvetica", 16))
C1=Entry(root,bd=5)

Image = Label(root, text="Enter Image", fg="Blue", font=("Helvetica", 16))
I1=Entry(root,bd=5)


Name.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
N1.pack()
City.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
C1.pack()
Image.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
I1.pack()




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question is too broad as written. A question should as one specific thing.

Comment: Okay @BryanOakley, Well I want the widgets to be places one below the other and also want the user to upload an image of his/her own against the IMAGE label. Please help!

Comment: It looks like you haven't even tried to make the entries visible. Go back and do a little research. Using `pack` (and `grid` and `place`) is well documented, and there are thousands of examples on the net.